# Pass property to component and then used it as conditional (ember js)

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-controllers, ember-components

application controller

```
isHotel_profile: function (){
    return this.get('currentPath') === 'hotel';
}.property('currentPath'),
```

component

```
{{#step-controller hotelPage=isHotel_profile}} {{/step-controller}}
```

and here's the component template

```
{{#if hotelPage}}
 hotel page 
{{else}}
 not hotel page
{{/if}}
```

i want to use the property as conditional how can i achieve that

Comment: `{{step-controller hotelPage=isHotel_profile}}`

Answer (score 2):

Your code is valid and should work fine.

Here's a demo: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nesete/1/edit?html,js,output

Note that you can simplify your computed property like this:

```
isHotel_profile: Ember.computed.equal('currentPath', 'hotel')
```